# Listening to events emitted from a programmatically mounted Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm mounting a Vue component programmatically in a mixin, in order to add the resulting HTML to a map popup. This works fine but I can't listen to events emitted by the component and I'm clueless as to how this can be done, if it can be done at all.

Here's the working code :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import myComponent from 'components/myComponent'

export default {
  methods: {
    makePopup(coordinates, data) {
      const popup = new Vue({
        ...myComponent,
        parent: this,
        propsData: data
      }).$mount()

      const content = popup.$el.outerHTML

      this.$map.showPopup(coordinates, content)

      popup.$destroy()
    }
  }
}
```

This is working but how (and when) can I listen to events emitted by `myComponent` in order to update the popup content afterwards? Those events do not seem to be fired after I'm instantiating / mounting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: To be clear, the problem arises here because the events emitted by `myComponent` do not seem to get fired after using the `$mount()` method on the Vue instance. I think it's related to compiling the instance but I'm really not sure it that's the right path or if it's even possible.

Comment: You can use a [global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) or [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: @max yes this is what I usually do but here the component is programmatically mounted which means events emitted in that component do not get fired as far as I can tell. So the question here how can I make sure they are fired in order to listen to them in my method

Answer (score 2):

Well answering my own question as I managed to find the right way : the events did get fired but I was simply destroying the component too soon (silly me)

```
const popup = new Vue({
  ...myComponent,
  parent: this,
  propsData: data
}).$mount()

this.$map.showPopup(coordinates, popup.$el.outerHTML)

popup.$on('complete', () => {
  // update popup content code
  popup.$destroy()
})
```